# Use abstract module as part of type definition separate from module

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use the module type `Partial_information` which is constructed via the functor `Make_partial_information` as the type of the field `contents` in the type `Cell.t`. However, I'm getting the error `Unbound module Partial_information`.

```
open Core

(* module which is used as argument to functor *)
module type Partial_type = sig
  type t
  val merge : old:t -> new_:t -> t
end

(* type of result from functor *)
module type Partial_information = sig
  type a
  type t = a option
  val merge : old:t -> new_:t -> t
  val is_nothing : t -> bool
end

(* The functor *)
module Make_partial_information(Wrapping : Partial_type):
  (Partial_information with type a = Wrapping.t)
= struct
  type a = Wrapping.t
  type t = a option

  let merge ~(old : t) ~(new_ : t) =
    match (old, new_) with
    | (None, None) -> None
    | (None, Some a) -> Some a
    | (Some a, None) -> Some a
    | (Some a, Some b) -> (Wrapping.merge ~old:a ~new_:b) |> Some

  let is_nothing (it: t) : bool = (is_none it)
end

(* Checking to make sure understanding of functor is correct *)
module Int_partial_type = struct
  type t = int
  let merge ~old ~new_ = new_ [@@warning "-27"]
end

module Int_partial_information = Make_partial_information(Int_partial_type)

(* Trying to use _any_ type which might have been created by the functor as a field in the record *)
module Cell = struct
  type id = { name : string ; modifier : int }
  type t = {
    (* Error is here stating `Unbound module Partial_information` *)
    contents : Partial_information.t ;
    id : id
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module types are specifications for modules. They do not define types by themselves. They are also not constructed by functors in any way. 
Consequently, it is hard to tell what you are trying to do.
As far I can see, you can simply define your cell type with a functor:

```
module Cell(P : Partial_information) = struct
  type id = { name : string ; modifier : int }
  type partial
  type t = {
    contents : P.t;
    id : id
  }
end
```

Or it might be even simpler to make the cell type polymorphic:

```
  type 'a cell = {
    contents : 'a;
    id : id
  }
```

since the type in itself is not particularly interesting nor really dependent upon
the type of contents.

P.S:
It is possible to use first class modules and GADTs to existentially quantify over a specific implementation of a module type. But it is unclear if it is worthwhile to explode your complexity budget here:

```
type 'a partial_information = (module Partial_information with type a = 'a)
module Cell = struct
  type id = { name : string ; modifier : int }
  type t = E: {
    contents : 'a ;
    partial_information_implementation: 'a partial_information;
    id : id
  } -> t
end
```

Comment: To clarify the GADT example, the type parameter `'a` is shared between both the `contents` and `partial_information_implementation` fields constraining both guaranteeing there is an implementation of the module for the given type?

Comment: Yes. The GADT gives you the information that there is a some unknown type `'a` such that `contents` is of type `'a`, and `partial_information_implementation` is a implementation of partial_information for this type `'a`. A consequence is that you can only use the `contents` value with the functions packed in `partial_module_information`.